Selenium ChromeDriver hanging on start in Docker container
I have an automated scraping routine using Python and Selenium that I use to pull together data. I had been running it in a Docker container, then switched to just running it in a terminal because I was having to do some tweaks to the code. I'm going back to Docker, but when I run the container, the process just stalls when it's starting the Chrome driver:
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options)

There isn't an error message or anything. The process just sits there doing nothing. Maybe there's some diagnostic stuff that I'm not seeing because of how the container logs and exec output interact with the process itself, but it's just a whole bunch of nothing. The container is doing something, and it's not an out-and-out freeze because it responds to a signal timeout and keyboard interrupts still work.
The vanilla webdriver.Chrome() command without arguments spits back an error almost immediately, as do most combinations of options. The one that seems to make the difference is the --no-sandbox argument. When I include it in the list, I get the stall.

I was having problems even if I used an older (11x) version of the Chrome driver in the container build. I ended up switching to Firefox, though that resulted in some reworking because of issues I was having with ActionChains hitting their marks.
